# GZipStream некорректно разархивирует файл типа csv

Tags: c#, csv, gzip, webclient

Почему-то файл разархивируется некорректно, на выходе получается файл размером 1Кб, внутри 1 строка исходного файла. Архивный файл скачивается отсюда: https://epss.cyentia.com/epss_scores-current.csv.gz.

Код программы:

```
public void DownloadExcelCsv(string url)
{
    string pathFile = path + @"\epss.csv.gz";

    using (WebClient web = new WebClient())
    {
        web.DownloadFile(new Uri(url[i]), pathFile[i]);
    }

    Decompressed(pathFile);
}

private void Decompressed(string file)
{
    string decomprssedFile = path + @"\epss.csv";

    using (FileStream sourceFile = File.OpenRead(file))
    {
        using (GZipStream gZip = new GZipStream(sourceFile, CompressionMode.Decompress))
        {
            using (FileStream targetFile = File.Create(decomprssedFile))
            {        
                gZip.CopyTo(targetFile);

                MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Восстановление файла {0} завершено.\nБыло: {1}, стало: {2}",
                        sourceFile.Name,
                        sourceFile.Length,
                        targetFile.Length));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Как вы это поняли? Надеюсь не смотрели размер файла в момент открытого `MessageBox`, который останавливает поток? Вообще, не используйте его для отладки! Также, `WebClient` в C# является устаревшим, используйте `HttpClient`.

Comment: `new Uri(url[i]), pathFile[i]` в этом месте код не компилируется. Отредактируйте вопрос, исправьте опечатки в коде.